# Export C source code and results in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I have the following block of code in my org file:

```
#+begin_src C -n :exports both :results output
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("This will work!");
return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

When I compile to a PDF the only result is the `"This will work"` string. Its only half of what I want. I want the source code and the result to be presented in the PDF. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Im using emacs on Mac osX with a org version of 7.9.3

Comment: Tried your example and I get both code and result exported. Org-mode version 8.2.5e on Linux. What happens with `:exports code`?

Comment: I still only get the result, i.e. "This will work"